# Remove horizontal movement / wiggle from iPhone optimized pages

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

I'm trying to optimize our News pages for iPhone. One problem I've noticed is that I'm able to tap and move the page horizontally (i.e. wiggle).

My question is, how I can prevent this horizontal movement from happening?

All of our News pages have this problem. Here are a couple examples:

- [With picture](http://bit.ly/lExGi7)
- [Without picture](http://bit.ly/lYw931)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "overflow-x: hidden" on the body.

Answer (score 11):

Something is definitely set greater than your device width. Add the following to your css to find the culprit.

`* {
    border-style:solid;
}`

You can then narrow down your search by setting `border-color:red;` to individual classes/tags/ids.

Comment: Now I see why this happens. It would have been impossible to find out by myself. Many thanks.

Comment: The `overflow-x: hidden` didn't work for me but this found the culprit in no time, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting user-scalable=0; and see if that has any effect.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it's still scrolling horizontally. Do you know of anything else I can try?

Comment: It sounds like one of your page elements is > 320px

Comment: I can't figure out what it is. I've tried deleting all the content from the page. Then it comes down to a CSS file, or jQuery, or my viewport meta. Each time I delete one it fixes it, but those are key files. I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: I'm out of ideas unfortunately. Did you try the overflow tag suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me too and it was the result of an extra closing div tag. Once I removed the extra `</div>`, the horizontal "wiggle" didn't happen any more.

Answer (score 0):

I too, had the iPhone "wiggles" on a web page. It ended up being caused by an image that was wider than the column width it sat in (it was the last column in the row using Twitter Bootstrap). You might be thinking "obvious", but it's hard to spot when the image background matches the page background.

Just make the image responsive, or smaller than the column width - that solved it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Taking the idea from other websites, most of big sites have a mobile site. look at those (the only one i know is facebook m.facebook.com) you can maybe see how the css is done. possible way of doing this is %. I would suggest to take out the sidebar for the mobile version. big pictures should be taken out or be resized so the browser doesn't have scroll bar side to side.

Comment: I need to use the same HTML page for both the desktop and mobile versions. They way I'm optimizing for iPhone is using display:none on the sidebar. Is there a better way to do this?